# How to add space after the text of a node but before a child element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is my sample XML:

```
<index>
    <indextext>
        <index.text1>Here goes some text<link attribute1="this" attribute2="that">and here is a link</link></index.text1>
    </indextext>
</index>
```

Now my problem is that I need to separate the text of the `index.text1` node and the `link` node.

Here's the thing. I tried doing this by getting the `preceding-sibling` of the `link` node, and I was able to actually do it, but then for some reason I lose the link attributes - in other words, that link contains attributes that enable it to link to a different document, which are in this case lost. NB: As soon as I mess with the `<template match="link">`, I lose those attributes.

What I did was this:

```
  <xsl:template match="index.text1//link">
    <xsl:text><![CDATA[  ]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>    
  </xsl:template>
```

... but that doesn't work, as explained in the paragraph above.

My question would be how to somehow either select the text that comes before the `link` node, or how to select the `link` node itself and enter space before it, but preserve all the attributes?

**BONUS QUESTION** - is there a way for me to automatically select a bunch of different nodes that all start with the name `index.text`? For example, is there a way I can automagically select `index.text`, `index.text1`, `index.text2` etc? Would `index.text*` work?

**SOLVED** - I figured out what the problem was. Basically I needed to call another template that is in the "main" code that actually handles rendering the document links. Still a lot more code to familiarize myself with!

Comment: for your bonus question: yes, xpath has support for pattern matching by using functions. http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want a space in front of all those link elements then simply do

```
  <xsl:template match="index.text1//link">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>   
  </xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As for wild card element matching, use

```
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'index.text')]//link">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>   
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to insert the space (well it's practically the same method that I used), but the "attributes are still lost" - well, they are not really lost. The problem I see is that normally the `link` node would get converted to an `a` node in the HTML itself, however, in this case for some reason the closing of the link node `</link>` disappears from the HTML - and as such, the `link` node remains in the HTML. Again, this only happens IFF I mess with the `link` node template, and not if I leave it be. Very odd... Any help there?

Comment: @Deusdies, well if you want to transform the `link` elements then obviously calling the identity template that merely copies it will not work. You should instead call a template that transforms the element e.g. replace `<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>` with `<xsl:call-template name="link-to-a"/>` and e.g. `<xsl:template name="link-to-a"><a><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></a></xsl:template>`. And then of course you need templates for the attributes of the `link` element.